# (MASM32) When using call ReadString to read integer values separated with spaces, is there any way to treat them as individual integers?

Tags: string, assembly, integer, irvine32, masm32

After declaring the space in BYTE format as follows, 
`key BYTE 31 DUP(0)`
,Receive a small number of integers separated by spaces like this : `-3 4 1 5 0 -7`.

So the code will be like this :

```
mov edx,OFFSET key
mov ecx,SIZEOF key
call ReadString
```

But since I used `ReadString`, I think pretty complex process is required to distinguish whether the '-' is attached or not, or whether it is blank, and if so, left ones will be number, etc.

Is there a way to implement this, or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: @prl As far as I know, it is supported by the Irvine32 library. Has a description 'Reads a string from a keyboard, terminated by the enter key.'

Comment: Doesn’t Irvine also have a ReadInteger function?

Comment: @prl Yes, there is a ReadInt function, but I was not sure if I can read more than one integers separated by spaces, just like I mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah I’m not sure either, but I think it will read one integer each time you call it.

Comment: @prl Maybe I just have to use ReadString, and by checking every address in key, separate numbers manually. And put those numbers in new byte array, which will be store integer values, not string.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but why not just use ReadInt? That’s what it is for and it will be way easier.

Comment: @prl I'm not sure how to use ReadInt because there will be random number of integers, so I'm not sure how many times I should call it...

Comment: Oh, I see—you want to read until the end of the line, and ReadInt doesn’t tell you when you’ve reached the end of the line. Then I guess you’re right—you have to use ReadString and parse the string yourself.

Comment: There’s a function ParseInteger32